# In MySQl, how to get the sum of data for an item from multiple table links

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like below.

```
Table 1
Name Value  Details

A     1     XXA
B     2     XXB
C     3     XXC

Table 2     

Name     Table1 Name    Data
1          A            1234
2          A            2345
3          B            4567
4          C            5678
```

And

```
Table 3     


Name    Table2Data  Amount
Ran1    1234         10
Ran2    2345         20
Ran3    4567         30
Ran4    4567         40
Ran5    5678         50
Ran6    1234         60
```

I need to get the result of query like below

```
Total Amount for each item in Table 1                   

Table 1 Row 1 (A)   Table 1 Row2 (B)    Table 1 Row 3 ( C)  ----
       90                  70                 50            ----
```

How can we achieve the same. From three tables i need to get the values, but need to arrange it in columns like above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a conditional sum. Like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='A' THEN Table3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='B' THEN Table3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='C' THEN Table3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM
    `Table1`
    JOIN Table2
        ON Table1.Name=Table2.Table1Name
    JOIN Table3
        ON Table2.Data=Table3.Table2Data
```

Comment: Actually, it's not clear from the OP whether he wants to aggregate all three tables together.

Comment: i dont want to hard code any column names, it should be taken from the other table, because all the tables are dynamic, anytime new values can come to the table.

Comment: The same only i m currently using, but the problem  i face is dynamic table s so need to query values and generate report.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need for conditional sums, you can use `GROUP BY` to group rows together from `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT 
    Table1.Name, SUM(Table3.Amount)
FROM 
    Table1
    JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Table1Name
    JOIN Table3 ON Table2.Data = Table3.Table2Data
GROUP BY Table1.Name
```

Comment: if in case i have one more table , Table 0, and for each table 0 item  there is an entry in all the three other tables,  First column should be table 0 and  then rows from table1 as next columns.

Comment: @VeenaSujith You mean you want to join another table to the query?

Comment: Based on a category, which may be there in 4th table, linked to other tables, i need to get the amount for each one in table 1. Something like Cat1 -- amoint for each row in table1, Cat2 -- amount for each row in table1... like that

Comment: column1 will be Catg names, and remaining columns will be rows of table1, and data within each of these columns will be the amount.

Comment: You might want to edit your original question to outline the additional table's schema. Basically you will need to JOIN this table again.

Comment: actually i am able to get all the data from joins and query, but i need to arrange it in Row/column wise.... colum names should be each Name from table 1, i dont want to hard code the same.

Comment: Instead of doing SUM(CASE WHEN Name='A' THEN Table3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='B' THEN Table3.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS B, i want to take the values dynamicallly